# UDP connection responses not received by client

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp, nat

I'm having trouble implementing an UDP connection because when I try it inside a LAN it works but when someone from inside a NAT tries to connect to the public server address, it fails because the packets sent from the server as response, never reach the client.

My protocol is as follows:

1. Client A send a byte as connection request to the server.
2. Server B creates a new socket for the client and responds a byte from there to the client port reported in the recvfrom() call. Never reaches the client.

I also tried:

Doing many calls sending a byte each for step 1.

Doing many calls sending a byte each for step 2.

Client code:

```
#define GPK_CONSOLE_LOG_ENABLED
#include "gpk_stdsocket.h"
#include "gpk_sync.h"

int main() {
    ::gpk::tcpipInitialize();
    sockaddr_in         sa_server           = {AF_INET};
    while(true) {
//#define MAKE_IT_WORK
#if defined MAKE_IT_WORK
        ::gpk::tcpipAddressToSockaddr({{192,168,0,2}, 9898}, sa_server);
#else
        ::gpk::tcpipAddressToSockaddr({{201,235,131,233}, 9898}, sa_server);
#endif
        ::gpk::SIPv4        addrRemote          = {};
        SOCKET              handle              = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        ree_if(INVALID_SOCKET == handle, "Failed to create socket.");
        sockaddr_in         sa_client           = {AF_INET};
        gpk_necall(::bind(handle, (sockaddr *)&sa_client, sizeof(sockaddr_in)), "Failed to bind listener to address");
        char                commandToSend       = '1';
        int                 sa_length           = sizeof(sa_server);
        gpk_necall(sendto(handle, (const char*)&commandToSend, (int)sizeof(char), 0, (sockaddr *)&sa_server, sa_length), "Failed to send connect request to server.");
        {
            sockaddr_in         sa_battery          = sa_server;
            for(uint32_t j=3; j < 3; ++j) {
            for(uint32_t i=16*1024; i < 64*1024; ++i) {
                sa_battery.sin_port = htons((u_short)i);
                gpk_necall(sendto(handle, (const char*)&commandToSend, (int)sizeof(char), 0, (sockaddr *)&sa_battery, sa_length), "Failed to send connect request to server.");
                //::gpk::sleep(1);
            }}
        }
        ::gpk::tcpipAddressFromSockaddr(sa_server, addrRemote);
        info_printf("Send connect request to server: %c to %u.%u.%u.%u:%u", commandToSend, GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrRemote));

        char                connectAcknowledge  = 0;
        sa_server.sin_port  = 0;
        gpk_necall(recvfrom(handle, (char *)&connectAcknowledge, (int)sizeof(char), 0, (sockaddr *)&sa_server, &sa_length), "Failed to receive response from server");
        addrRemote          = {};
        ::gpk::tcpipAddressFromSockaddr(sa_server, addrRemote);
        info_printf("Received connect response from server: %c from %u.%u.%u.%u:%u.", connectAcknowledge, GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrRemote));
        ::gpk::sleep(1000);
        gpk_safe_closesocket(handle);
    }
    ::gpk::tcpipShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
#define GPK_CONSOLE_LOG_ENABLED
#include "gpk_stdsocket.h"
#include "gpk_sync.h"

int main() { 
    ::gpk::tcpipInitialize();
    sockaddr_in             sa_server               = {};
    ::gpk::SIPv4            addrLocal               = {{}, 9898};
    ::gpk::tcpipAddress(0, 9898, 1, ::gpk::TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL_UDP, addrLocal);
    ::gpk::tcpipAddressToSockaddr(addrLocal, sa_server);

    SOCKET                  handle                  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    ree_if(INVALID_SOCKET == handle, "Failed to create socket.");
    gpk_necall(::bind(handle, (sockaddr *)&sa_server, sizeof(sockaddr_in)), "Failed to bind listener to address");
    info_printf("Server listening on %u.%u.%u.%u:%u.", GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrLocal));
    while(true) {
        ::gpk::SIPv4            addrLocalClient         = addrLocal;
        addrLocalClient.Port = 0;
        SOCKET                  clientHandle            = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

        sockaddr_in             sa_server_client        = {AF_INET};
        ::gpk::tcpipAddressToSockaddr(addrLocalClient, sa_server_client);
        gpk_necall(::bind(clientHandle, (sockaddr *)&sa_server_client, sizeof(sockaddr_in)), "Failed to bind listener to address");

        sockaddr_in             sa_client               = {AF_INET};
        int                     client_length           = sizeof(sa_client);
        char                    connectReceived         = 0;
        gpk_necall(::recvfrom(handle, (char*)&connectReceived, (int)sizeof(char), 0, (sockaddr*)&sa_client, &client_length), "Failed to receive connect request.");
        ::gpk::SIPv4            addrRemote;
        ::gpk::tcpipAddressFromSockaddr(sa_client, addrRemote);
        info_printf("Received connect request: %c from %u.%u.%u.%u:%u.", connectReceived, GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrRemote));

        char                    commandToSend           = '2';
        //::gpk::tcpipAddressFromSockaddr(sa_server, addrLocal);
        ::gpk::tcpipAddress(clientHandle, addrLocal);
        info_printf("Sending connect response %c from %u.%u.%u.%u:%u to %u.%u.%u.%u:%u.", commandToSend, GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrLocal), GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrRemote));
        ::gpk::sleep(10);
        ree_if(INVALID_SOCKET == clientHandle, "Failed to create socket.");
        for(uint32_t i=16*1024; i < 65535; ++i)
            gpk_necall(::sendto(clientHandle, (const char*)&commandToSend, (int)sizeof(char), 0, (sockaddr*)&sa_client, sizeof(sockaddr_in)), "Failed to respond.");
        info_printf("Sent connect response %c from %u.%u.%u.%u:%u to %u.%u.%u.%u:%u.", commandToSend, GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrLocal), GPK_IPV4_EXPAND(addrRemote));
        if(handle != clientHandle)
            gpk_safe_closesocket(clientHandle);
    }
    ::gpk::tcpipShutdown();
    return 0; 
}
```

Note: I left the sample udp_server and udp_client projects at https://github.com/asm128/gpk in case you want a working example that compiles the working and broken cases conditionally by uncommenting `//#define MAKE_IT_WORK` and by placing your IP address in place of mine.

Comment: Add the code you tried to the question. Without all the parts that aren't important.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `serverInstance.Socket.Handle` but passing `serverInstance.Socket` as a file descriptor in later calls?

Comment: @dbush it's a RAII that destroys SOCKET in Handle if it goes out of scope. I can use it as the original type when it's const.

Comment: Interesting that you don't do the same for the client socket.  We need to see more code here.  This also looks like C++, not C.

Comment: Your comment is irrelevant to the question, and the socket code is the same for both C and C++. There is no "more code" to see, other than the variable declaration. Btw, sizeof(::gpk::SUDPCommand) equals to 1.

Comment: It is very relevant, as the inconsistency suggests you may be doing something wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can compile and run that replicates your problem.

Comment: In the posted code, none of the return values of the function calls are being examined.  Was the error-checking omitted in the post for the sake of brevity, or are you really not checking for any errors?  If the latter, then you're making life unecessarily difficult for yourself, because examining return values is how you find out which of your calls are failing.

Comment: @dbush What inconsistencies are you talking about? I suppose the code I posted is correct then. In my tests the code works correctly inside the NAT and I explicitly removed the error checking code because immibis said "without the parts that aren't important" and I already checked return values and they're all ok.

However, after testing this code in isolation, I can see it works correctly, so maybe something else is breaking it up in the middle. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PabloAriel In the server code you assign to `serverInstance.Socket.Handle` and subsequently read `serverInstance.Socket`, while in the client code you assign to `client.Socket.Handle` and read from `client.Socket.Handle`.  That's inconsistent.

Comment: @PabloAriel I also see that the server stores the client address in `sa_client` for `recvfrom` but the corresponding `sendto` call instead uses `sa_remote`.  You don't show any code that sets these.  A [mcve] is needed to see if the problem is in your or elsewhere, although I'm leaning towards the former since an outgoing UDP packet should open a firewall hole for a return packet with the same IP/port pair for both sides.

Comment: I fixed the names you it's easier for you to understand. The code is crystal clear for anyone to see, and from your own words I understand it's perfectly fine as you try to insult me by saying that I did wrong anyway "in a secret way". If you want a working example that you can test in your LAN (but that will fail outside a LAN) you will have to download it from https://github.com/asm128/gpk and build and run udp_server and udp_client. It builds and runs out of the box if you have VS2019 .

Comment: The code is now constantly changing as I make changes to test on the other end. It may not be the version I'm currently testing. I clarify this because you're gonna come and try to insult me back.

Comment: Now, if the problem is in setting up the variables, I'm sure that with your experience and having written so much code about UDP, you can show me how they should be set. Right?

Comment: It seems you figured out the problem yourself.  The server needs to send responses using the same socket that requests were received on.  As I mentioned before, for UDP to work through a NAT the port numbers have to match in both directions.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to leave the listener socket free and respond from a new port. That's what TCP does. I need to do the same thing.

Comment: Also, fixing the names isn't a matter of making things easier to understand, it's a matter of accuracy.  Computers do **exactly** what you tell them, so if that was your real code it may have explained the problem.  Code posted here should be the exact code you run that exhibits your problem, otherwise you're wasting everyone's time.  And it's not insulting to suggest that the problem may be in your code based on the expertise of the person offering assistance.

Comment: Yet the code I'm posting is 100% fine. The problem is not in my code, or in the way I'm doing it, and I explained it correctly and mentioned that the server was creating a new socket for the response. You could have give me the same answer (that the port needs to be the same) just by reading that and not looking at any code at all.

Comment: @PabloAriel Except that you originally posted that you tried using both a new socket and the existing socket and both approaches failed.

Comment: I still don't understand how I'm supposed to implement UDP punchthrough if I have the limitations you mentioned. According to you, it would be close to impossible. Currently I'm trying sending a packet to each port above 16k (i get assigned higher than that) and a battery of connect responses from the server, and yet I don't get the response from the port for which now I sent a request.

Comment: UDP is connectionless, so you have to use a single socket for all communications so that the server port number remains the same.  It's not the same as TCP.  A TCP socket is defined by both a local IP/port and a remote IP/port, while a UDP socket is defined by only a local IP/port.

Comment: Yet, I've read that VoIP and videoconferencing services do implement udp hole punching. How do they do it? And also this doesn't explain why by sending a request to every port, I don't get the response from that port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your responses are not getting back to the client because you're using a separate socket to send responses back.  This socket has a different local port number than the socket that received the packet from the client, so to the NAT it appears to be coming from a different source and is therefore not forwarded.

When a UDP datagram exits a NAT, the NAT keeps track of the destination IP and port along with the local IP and port used by the NAT and matches that with the original source IP and port on the inside network.  For an incoming packet to pass back through to the original source, the source IP and port of the incoming must match the destination IP and port of the prior outgoing packet, and the destination IP and port of the incoming packet must match the IP and port of the NAT for the outgoing packet.  If that condition is met, the NAT forward the packet to the original source IP and port.  This is referred to as [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Let's illustrate this with an example.  Suppose you have the following hosts:

- server (outside of NAT): IP 192.168.0.10
- NAT: internal IP 192.168.0.1, external IP 10.0.0.1
- client (inside of NAT): IP 10.0.0.2

Your server creates a socket bound to point 9898 and waits.  Your client then creates a socket bound to port 0, meaning a random port is chosen.  Let's assume it's port 10000.  The client then sends a UDP packet to 192.168.0.10:9898.  So the packet has:

- Source IP: 10.0.0.2
- Destination IP: 192.168.0.10
- Source port: 10000
- Destination port: 9898

The packet then passes through the NAT, which adjusts the source IP and port so responses can be sent back to the client.  It chooses port 15000.  So now the packet looks like this:

- Source IP: 192.168.0.1
- Destination IP: 192.168.0.10
- Source port: 15000
- Destination port: 9898

If the NAT later sees a packet coming from the outside network with same IP/port pairs above but with source/destination reversed, it will send it to 10.0.0.2:10000.

The server then receives this packet.  But now you create a new socket on the server and bind it to port 0, so a random port is chosen, let's say 12000.  The server then uses this socket to send the response back where it came.  So the response packet looks like this:

- Source IP: 192.168.0.10
- Destination IP: 192.168.0.1
- Source port: 12000
- Destination port: 15000

The NAT then receives this packet, and needs to decide whether to forward it to an internal host.  Had the source port been 9898 it would change the destination IP/port to 10.0.0.2:10000 and send it there.  But it doesn't match, so the NAT drops the packet.

The server needs to use the same socket that received the packet from the client to send the response back.  If it does the packet will look like this:

- Source IP: 192.168.0.10
- Destination IP: 192.168.0.1
- Source port: 9898
- Destination port: 15000

And the NAT will forward it to the client because it matches the packet that went out but with the source/destination swapped.

With regard to the server handling requests from multiple clients, it needs to keep track of where the request came from and have some sort of mechanism to keep state on each client to determine the appropriate response to send.

Comment: Thanks! Though it still doesn't explain why, if I'm sending 10 packets to every port above 165535 after sending the connection request, the infinite response sending I do after asking for the new port isn't reaching the client. Now, I'm sending a packet to EVERY port, more than once, so the packet should come back, because I'm expecting a connection response from every port above that number, right? Or what am I missing?

Comment: In the posted code, the client first sends to the server at port 9898, which the server should receive, then it sends 3 times each to ports 16384 to 65535  which the server is not listening on so it shouldn't see those.  On the server side, after getting a client request it sends a response 65535 - 16384 times to the same NAT port, none of which the client should see because you're using a different socket which has a different server port.  If you used the same socket for sending and receiving, the client should get all of those responses back.

Comment: You're right that it might be an impossible problem I wanted to solve. I picked up and built some UDP hole punching examples I've found and they have the same problem, and they don't work. They seem to be doing pretty much the same I did in my last tests. Also, I modified the code so now I'm constantly sending from both the server and the client to the other end, the server always to the initial request port and the client to every possible port in the server. Yet, even when port number collision is obviously met, I'm unable to get a single byte to pass through.

Comment: @PabloAriel Most likely, every outgoing packet from the client gets mapped to a different NAT port because the destination port is different.  Running wireshark on the server should confirm that.

Comment: Thanks! You found what I was failing in, which was proper debugging of the communication. My fault, I admit, and that will probably give me a definitive answer even if it's the one I don't like. I'll let you know what I find out as soon as I find the time to try.

Comment: Sadly, I wasn't able to get it to work after throwing packets to every single port, so I assume this is not a good way to solve the problem and I will leave this system for LAN connections while for NA-Translated comms I'm gonna handle connections through a single socket, which shouldn't be a problem if I keep services independent enough. 

Thanks for your help.